# How to display all the values

Tags: vb6

Using VB6

I am using checkbox and combobox in a Form.

When i click the check box, the combobox will enable, by default combobox will be disable.

Code.

```
Private Sub chkbox1_Click()
   combobox1.enable = true
End Sub

Private Sub chkbox2_Click()
   combobox2.enable = true
End Sub
```

Output Code is

```
If chkbox1.Value = 1 Then
    sql2 = "Select * from table1 where value = '" & combobox1 & "' "
ElseIf chkbox2.Value = 1 Then

    sql2 = "Select * from table1 where value = '" & combobox2 & "'"
Else 
    sql2 = "Select * from table1"
End If
```

The above code is working, but when i click the two checkbox, then two combobox are enabled, then i run the query it is showing the combobox1 value.

For example

```
I selected the value = 50 from combobox1 (checkbox1 clicked)
I selected the value = 100 from combobox2 (checkbox2 clicked)
```

when i run the output code, then output is display the value where value = 50, it is not showing value = 100 also.

It should show both values in the output code

How to solve this issue.

Need vb6 code help

Comment: In `If-ElseIf`, if one condition satisfies, the rest of the condition statements don't get executed. If you want to get both, try keeping the condition `chkcombin.Value=1` with an if statement.

Comment: You description is not very clear. For example, what is "chkcombin1"? I suggest you add a screenshot of your form for further clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If chkcombin1.Value = 1 And chkcombin2.Value = 0 Then
    sql2 = "Select * from table1 where value = '" & combobox1 & "' "
ElseIf chkcombin2.Value = 1 And chkcombin1.Value = 1 Then

    sql2 = "Select * from table1 where value = '" & combobox2 & "'"
ElseIf chckcombin1.Value = And chkcombin2.Value = 1
    sql2 = "Select * from table 1 Where value = '" & combobox1 & "' and value = '" & combobox2 & "'"
Else
    sql2 = "Select * from table1"
End If
```

What is happening is if both are checked the first case is true, since `chkcombin1.Value = 1`
So you need to check to make sure that the other box is unchecked.

**Edit op comments**

Since you have multiple checkboxes then I would suggest this:

**this isn't tested nor is it optimal but it should give you an idea**

```
Dim select As String = "Select * from table 1"

'This needs to be a field for the whole class
Dim where As String = ""

If chkcombin1.Value = 1 Then
   where += CreateCaluse(combobox1)
End If

'Then do that for each of your comboboxes

'Then
sql2 = select + where

Private Function CreateClause(ByVal comboboxValue As String) As String
    If where = "" Then
        Return " Where value = '" & comboboxValue & "'"
    Else
        Return " and value = '" & comboboxValue & "'"
    End If
End Function
```

SO what that does is writes the no checkboxes checked part of your statement, then it prepares the where clause, using a function to generate the necessary parts, if the where clause is an empty string it writes what it should be for 1 where, then appends all of the necessary `and` clauses. Finally it combines the statement together. If there is nothing in the where clause then you get the `Select * from table1`

Comment: I have more than 10 checkbox, so for that any alternative code is there or i have to do like this...?

Comment: @Gopal well then that actually changes how you should do this completely. I'll make some edits and suggestions

Comment: SOrry I switched to .Net my mistake fixing

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 0=1"
If chkbox1.Value = vbChecked Then
    sql2 = sql2 & " OR value = '" & Replace(combobox1.Text, "'", "''") & "'"
End If
If chkbox2.Value = vbChecked Then
    sql2 = sql2 & " OR value = '" & Replace(combobox2.Text, "'", "''") & "'"
End If
If chkbox3.Value = vbChecked Then
    ...
```

Or if you are using control arrays the code would be much reduced

```
sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 0=1"
For i = 1 To 10
    If chkbox(i).Value = vbChecked Then
        sql2 = sql2 & " OR value = '" & Replace(ComboBox(i).Text, "'", "''") & "'"
    End If
Next
```